# How to pass values from uitextfield to CGAffineTransformMakeRotation

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(90);

How can I send mytextfield.text to CGAffineTransformMakeRotation
like : CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(mytextfield.text);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to convert the string into a number.

```
CGAffineTransformMakeRotation([mytextfield.text floatValue]);
```

Comment: You may need to convert degrees to radians as well.

Comment: Maybe he wanted 90 radians :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(__ANGLE__) ((__ANGLE__) / 180.0 * M_PI)

-(IBAction)RotateButtonPressed:(id)sender;
{   
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
    arrow.center = CGPointMake(151.0,80.0);
arrow.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS([degrees.text floatValue]));
    [UIView commitAnimations];


}
```

Thats how I did convert from radians to degrees for CGAffineTransformMakeRotation

For anyones future reference